# jVectorMaps image markers

Tags: javascript, jvectormap

I know this questions has been asked but the op didn't provide any code and I can't edit his answer obviously, so I'll start a new one. My objective is to replace the dot with a custom drop-pin marker that I will eventually have some other action for it. So as a kicker, such action must be identified somehow (perhaps and id) so that I can call it from jQuery, CSS, or javascript and give it some use.

**Background**:

I extracted the map of Pennsylvania from jVectorMaps and the code from the section that explains how to use marker images from this link [marker-icons](http://jvectormap.com/examples/marker-icons/).

**This is the original code**:

```
$(function(){
   var plants = [
   {name: 'KKG', coords: [49.9841308, 10.1846373], status: 'activeUntil2018'},
   {name: 'KKK', coords: [53.4104656, 10.4091597], status: 'closed'},
   {name: 'KWG', coords: [52.0348748, 9.4097793], status: 'activeUntil2022'},
   {name: 'KBR', coords: [53.850666, 9.3457603], status: 'closed', offsets: [0, 5]}
];

new jvm.Map({
   container: $('#map'),
   map: 'de_merc',
   markers: plants.map(function(h){ return {name: h.name, latLng: h.coords} }),
   labels: {
      markers: {
        render: function(index){
          return plants[index].name;
        },
        offsets: function(index){
          var offset = plants[index]['offsets'] || [0, 0];

          return [offset[0] - 7, offset[1] + 3];
        }
      }
   },
   series: {
     markers: [{
       attribute: 'image',
       scale: {
         'closed': '/img/icon-np-3.png',
         'activeUntil2018': '/img/icon-np-2.png',
         'activeUntil2022': '/img/icon-np-1.png'
       },
       values: plants.reduce(function(p, c, i){ p[i] = c.status; return p }, {}),
       legend: {
         horizontal: true,
         title: 'Nuclear power station status',
         labelRender: function(v){
           return {
           closed: 'Closed',
           activeUntil2018: 'Scheduled for shut down<br> before 2018',
           activeUntil2022: 'Scheduled for shut down<br> before 2022'
         }[v];
        }
      }
    }]
   }
  });
});
```

And this is my version which it does display the map, it does display the location, but only as a dot, not the marker. (See screenshot below) p.s. I don't care about the legend. I'm doing something else for that.

**My code:**

```
//------------- Vector maps -------------//
     var prison = [
       {name: 'Albion', coords: [41.890611, -80.366454], status: 'active', offsets: [0, 2]}
];


$('#pa-map').vectorMap({
    map: 'us-pa_lcc_en',
    scaleColors: ['#f7f9fe', '#29b6d8'],
    normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
    hoverOpacity: 0.7,
    hoverColor: false,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    regionStyle:{
        initial: {
            fill: '#dde1e7',
            "fill-opacity": 1,
            stroke: '#f7f9fe',
            "stroke-width": 0,
            "stroke-opacity": 0
        },
        hover: {
            "fill-opacity": 0.8
        },
        selected: {
            fill: 'yellow'
        }
    },
    markers: prison.map(function(h){ return {name: h.name, latLng: h.coords} }),
    labels: {
        markers: {
          render: function(index){
            return prison[index].name;
          },
          offsets: function(index){
            var offset = prison[index]['offsets'] || [0, 0];

            return [offset[0] - 7, offset[1] + 3];
          }
        }
    },
    series: {
      markers: [{
        attribute: 'image',
        scale: { 'active': '/img/map-marker-icon.png'},
        values: prison.reduce(function(p, c, i){ p[i] = c.status; return p }, {}),
      }]
    }
});
```

**My HTML**:

```
<div id="pa-map" style="width: 100%; height: 470px"></div>
```

**My CSS**:

Irrelevant. I'll design accordingly later.

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: are your marker images in the right location?

Comment: I checked that as well, They are

Comment: Have you checked the console for any logs?

Comment: nothing. No 404s, missing references, dependencies, or anything like that. Just a missing avatar that I am using in the account page (user images) Nothing that would be related to this

Comment: hmm, the only thing I'm seeing is that there's not a lot of documentation on the difference between `$.vectorMap()` and `new jvm.Map()`

Comment: Agreed.  Not much of a documentation period from the vendor.  I'm hoping someone here can share some light.  I know I can't be the only one that's ever attempted this.  Let's see

Comment: Best thing is probably to just read the source

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*To change dot to custom marker*   [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJdbjx)
If you read there source code they have option for initializing  *markerStyle* in *jvm.Map.defaultParam* and for *markerStyle* you can define it as image or fill (switch case is used here) i think in *jvm.Legend.prototype.render*

They also has Some Event

```
jvm.Map.apiEvents = {
    onRegionTipShow: "regionTipShow",
    onRegionOver: "regionOver",
    onRegionOut: "regionOut",
    onRegionClick: "regionClick",
    onRegionSelected: "regionSelected",
    onMarkerTipShow: "markerTipShow",
    onMarkerOver: "markerOver",
    onMarkerOut: "markerOut",
    onMarkerClick: "markerClick",
    onMarkerSelected: "markerSelected",
    onViewportChange: "viewportChange"
}
```

So here the code **UPDATE** you can also attach your function to onMarkerClick option

```js
function doWhatever(event, code, obj) {
  alert("Hello");
  console.log(event);
}

var prison = [{
  name: 'Albion',
  coords: [41.890611, -80.366454],
  status: 'active',
  offsets: [0, 2]
}];

var ab = $('#pa-map').vectorMap({
  map: 'us-pa_lcc_en',
  scaleColors: ['#f7f9fe', '#29b6d8'],
  normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
  hoverOpacity: 0.7,
  hoverColor: false,
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  regionStyle: {
    initial: {
      fill: '#dde1e7',
      "fill-opacity": 1,
      stroke: '#f7f9fe',
      "stroke-width": 0,
      "stroke-opacity": 0
    },
    hover: {
      "fill-opacity": 0.8
    },
    selected: {
      fill: 'yellow'
    }
  },
  markers: prison.map(function(h) {
    return {
      name: h.name,
      latLng: h.coords
    }
  }),
  labels: {
    markers: {
      render: function(index) {
        return prison[index].name;
      },
      offsets: function(index) {
        var offset = prison[index]['offsets'] || [0, 0];

        return [offset[0] - 7, offset[1] + 3];
      }
    }
  },
  markersSelectable: true,
  markerStyle: {
    initial: {
      image: "http://jvectormap.com/img/icon-np-2.png",

    },
  },
  onMarkerClick: function(event, code) {
    doWhatever(event, code, this);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://jvectormap.com/css/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://jvectormap.com/js/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bjornd/jvectormap/master/tests/assets/us/jquery-jvectormap-data-us-pa-lcc-en.js"></script>



<div id="pa-map" style="width: 100%; height: 470px"></div>
```

Comment: I'm testing this. It works with the world or US map but not with the PA map.

Comment: I'm loading World Map jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js Can you provide PA Map JS

Comment: Sure thing. I'll give you a github link.  And thanks for this

Comment: Give me a couple of minutes

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bjornd/jvectormap/master/tests/assets/us/jquery-jvectormap-data-us-pa-lcc-en.js

Comment: Did you update the codepen? Because I copied and pasted it in the codepen and it didn't work. Neither by running the Code Snippet

Comment: Yes i have updated just now ,try running in firefox  because chrome gives error as Refused to execute script from https://github..... because it s MIME type (text/plain)

Comment: you need to download that JS File Locally and then try running in chrome

Comment: how did you guys solved this. first i got circle markers, just tweaked it until it shows no markers at all.